# Union query in oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, union

I have a requirement in oracle as below.
There are two tables having Name,Dob,address of persons.

Table1

```
Personid   name       dob        adrs
1          Jack    05/06/1990    USA
2          Jill    05/06/1985    UK
```

Table2

```
Personid   name       dob        adrs
1          Jack    
3          Smith
```

I have to make an union query from two table such that
if name in both table are same only one row should return result like

```
Personid   name       dob        adrs
1          Jack    05/06/1990    USA
2          Jill    05/06/1985    UK
3          Smith
```

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
SELECT personid, name, dob, adrs 
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT personid, name, dob, adrs 
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t2.personid NOT IN (SELECT personid
                          FROM   tabl1);
```

Here i have used `PERSONID` instead of `NAME` to compare b/w tables.